# print(variable1.format(variable2)) How does the logic of the code work?

Tags: python-3.x

Example:

```
hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! {}"

print(joke_evaluation.format(hilarious))
```

What does ".format" do ? Why did we use empty {} (Curly Brackets) here? And when I run this code, how is it able to print False? How does this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when formating a string you can do it like this

```
"sometext {}".format("whatever is supposed to be places at curly brackets place")
```

which gives

```
"sometext whatever is supposed to be placed at curly brackets place"
```

what goes for the False, you sat hilarious to False, and python wil automaticly parse it as a string when formeting

Comment: In this Example :
print("Marry had a little lamb.")
print("Its fleeece was white as {}.".format('snow'))

The code also works without the .format like this :
print("Marry had a little lamb.")
print("Its fleeece was white as snow")

So what's the need of putting extra code, can you give me an example?

Comment: your a correct but in that case you already know what to put in, but let's say you dont know and for example want to use the input from a user, then you can format the varieble. 'inp = input("Whats your name: ")' 'print("Your name is {}".format(inp))'